# Hibernate initializing a group/collection of entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a query with fetches an entity in pages. Each page contains 100 entities. For those 100 entities I need to fetch some nested entities which are fetched lazy.

What happens is that I have 1 SELECT executed for main entities and then 100 SELECTs for nested ones.

I am looking for a way to initialize those 100 nested ones in bulk, so that in total I have 1 SELECT for main entity and 1 for nested ones.

My structure is as follows, and I would prefer if it is not changed (we had a lot of problems with EAGER fetches)

```
public class MyMainEntity {
    private NestedEntity nested;

    @Override
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "exFK_Nest_Enth"))
    public NestedEntity getNested() {
        ...
    }
```

Is there a way to do it with `Hibernate.initialize()`

Comment: Can you share the repository code? Also what kind of problems did you have with `eager` fetching?

Comment: Its just SimpleJpaRepository findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable) method. All kind of problems with different entities. So I would like to avoid that. But it seams that its not possible to be done with hibernate. I have decided to write special queries and select only fields which I need. That way nothing will be LAZY fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate Criteria query to fetch the MyMainEntity and use criteria.createAlias("nested", "ns", Criteria.Subselect). It will fire two query; one for fetching MyMainEntity and other for Nested with MyMainEntity query acting as subquery. And if you use Criteria.Join then it will fire only one query and fetching both MyMainActivity and Nested

Answer (score 0):

By default, hibernate recent versions it follows **JPA 2.0 spec**:

Relationships with:

```
ToMany: Lazy
ToOne: Eager
```

but if you're using an older version of Hibernate, all relations comes by default with `Lazy`

In that case when you want to try to retrieve child relations use `JOIN FETCH` , for example:

```
Select m from MyMainEntity m JOIN FETCH m.nested;
```